# Is there a callback for markers when they finished to load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I cannot find anywhere, neither in the docs, a callback for when the markers have finished to load on the map.

Comment: The [MarkerClustererPlus](https://github.com/googlemaps/v3-utility-library/tree/master/markerclustererplus) exposes a `clusteringend` event.

Comment: @MrUpsidown I'm not using the plus, also the trick I've posted works for single marker/circle and cluster

Comment: I was just suggesting this library as it exposes events that the one you are using doesn't... Other features should work just the same.

Comment: I appreciate the down vote, probably an explanation of why would be much helpful. Just to clearify tho, I have made this question to provide my own answer. As per what I am asking there isn’t really another way, unless you know and provide an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not find any other way on the docs or answers here on SO on how to solve "a callback or event when all markers are loaded in google maps" so I thought of sharing this trick I use:

1. create a loader
2. set a zoom like you want, gmap will think you moved it

   ```
   var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
     center: {lat: 40.600486, lng: 9.261252},
     zoomControl: true,
     zoom: 8,


     ...draw your pins and then set them normally in the map
     markerClusterer = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, mcOptions);

     ...now fake a zoom

     google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map,
     'zoom_changed',
     function(event) {
       console.log("All your markers are loaded");
       // remove the loader
     });
     map.setZoom(8);
   ```